# Add pixels to a raster image

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a georeferenced raster with water depth values and I would like to add more pixels in order to extend my raster as far as the coastline (like in the picture, dark blue has no values). How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: I would like to recommend **Close gaps with spline** tool using the coastline to create mask... but it can be laborious under QGIS Processing. For this case **Shrink and expand** (Expand option) might be more practical tool.

Comment: Thank you, Shrink and expand tool works. Unfortunately, the new pixels get the same values of the nearest pixels and this not good for water depth when you get closer to the coast.  I have found a solution to this issue by using the plugin SERVAL in QGIS, it is a very useful plugin, but you need to add/change pixel values one by one.

Comment: I understand. SERVAL is the best option working in QGIS environment. There is a tool to fill/change cell values at one go, SAGA **Change Grid Values - Flood Fill [interactive]** but it is only found in SAGA GUI, not in QGIS.

Comment: If you don't mind creating a mask layer from your coastline, I mean, create a raster of cell value `0` (zero) all over the land area, then you can use **Close gaps with spline**. The gap (nodata) cells between coast and your water will be filled by gradually decaying values.

Comment: Thank you @Kazuhito, I have tried with Close gaps with spline but it failed. I created a mask with my coastline with zeros all over the land and sea areas, and 1 on the coastline. Do I have to change any parameter before running Close gaps with spline?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea what went wrong. Is it possible to use **Close gaps with spline** tool without applying the mask, then clip the output by your coastline?

Comment: Yes, but the result is even worse! I will keep the map got with the Shrink and expand tool

Comment: That's too bad. Sorry. Let us wait for other suggestions.